# Ignoring a particular attribute of a specific Node while comparing xml files using XMLUnit

Tags: java, xmlunit

```
<!------------------------File1--------------------------------->
Node id="123">
 <to>Name</to>
 <from>User</from>
<Boolean id>123</Boolean id>
</Node >
 <!------------------------File2--------------------------------->
<Node id="12369">
<to>Name</to>
<from>User</from>
<Boolean id>123</Boolean id>
 </Node >
```

I have to ignore the attribute:boolean id from  Node up on comparing the files at specific node level.

I am using DiffBuilder

```
Diff diff = 
      DiffBuilder.compare(root).withTest(root2).checkForSimilar()
            .withNodeFilter(
                    node -> !(node.getNodeName().equals("Assoc_CIDB") || node.getNodeName().equals("Synoptics")))
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(es)).build();
```

Can someone suggest me a way how i can achieve the issues :
1.Ignore specific attributes on a specific node.
2.If the differences are at from attributes then i just compare and check to attributes details
I can achieve this using XMLUnit 2.x Iam New to XMLUnit so someone please help me accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see following class got used.How to add attribute filter to diff?? .IgnoreNoteId implements Predicate<Attr> {

    public boolean test(Attr attr) {
        return !("note".equals(attr.getOwnerElement().getNodeName())
            && "id".equals(attr.getNodeName()));
    }
}

Comment: Have you read the documentation https://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/master/org/xmlunit/builder/DiffBuilder.html#withAttributeFilter-org.xmlunit.util.Predicate-

Comment: I got that.Thank u   :-)    Is it possible to get Similarities using Diff ??